# Creating field for class from another class

Tags: java, constructor, field

I am trying to make field value for constructor from another class into a class.

```
public class Student {
        private String name;
        private int streetNum;
        private int houseNum; 
...
}
```

I want to reference these variables to field variable like this:

```
   private Student studentInfo = new Student(name, streetNum, houseNum);
```

Is there a way to do it?  I don't want the field variables to be static.

Answer (score 0):

in java constructors can have arguments so if you want to set those variables using those arguments you have to do something like this:

```
 public class Student {

 private String name;
 private int streetNum;
 private int houseNum;

 public Student(String name, int streetNum, houseNum){
   this.name = name; 

   /*if you want to use arguments that
   have same name has the variables you have 
   use "this.variable" to specify that you're reffering to the 
   variables of the class and not the arguments.
   the "this" field refferes to the class itself*/

   this.streetNum = streetNum;
   this.houseNum = houseNum;
  }
}
```